# Creation and annihilation operators for fermions from anticommutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, fermions, anticommutator

In a question, I was given that $a^{\dagger}a + a a^{\dagger} =1$ and asked to show what $a|n\rangle$ and $a^{\dagger}|n\rangle$ would be, given that $H|n\rangle=(a^{\dagger}a + 1/2)$.

I am getting the wrong answer for $a^{\dagger}$.

Call number operator $N=H-1/2$ and denote anticommutator by $\{\}$.

$\{N,a^{\dagger}\}=a^{\dagger}aa^{\dagger} + a^{\dagger}a^{\dagger}a$

$\{N,a^{\dagger}\}=a^{\dagger}(aa^{\dagger}+ a^{\dagger}a)=a^{\dagger}$

now for $a$, I get the same answer.

$\{N,a\}=a^{\dagger}aa + aa^{\dagger}a$

$\{N,a\}=a$

So then
$Na|n\rangle=(\{N,a\}-aN)|n\rangle=(a-an)|n\rangle=(1-n)a|n\rangle$

then you can do the same thing with $a^{\dagger}$ .

This leads to the eigenvectors differing by a constant, I think, which is *not* what we want, right?
in the end, per [this link](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/%7Evadim/Classes/11f/ffs.pdf) they have different properties.

What have I done wrong?
note that I cannot use the {a,a}=0 property or the counterpart with $a^{\dagger}$.

Edit: with the help of Mike (thanks) now I get it. following this to the end, for satisfaction:

$$ a|n\rangle = C_{a} |1-n\rangle $$

$$ \langle n| a^{\dagger}a|n\rangle = |C_{a}|^{2}  \langle 1-n|1-n\rangle $$

$$ n = |C_{a}|^{2} $$
repeating with $a^{\dagger}$

$$ \langle n| aa^{\dagger} |n\rangle = |C_{a^{\dagger}}|^{2}  \langle 1-n|1-n\rangle $$

$$ 1-n= |C_{a^{\dagger}}|^{2} $$

so they're not quite the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to compute
$[a^\dagger, N]$ rather than $\{A^\dagger, N\}$. Use
$$
[A,BC]= \{A,B\}C- B\{A,C\},
$$
to do this.

Mind you, your algebra is correct. If $n=1$ then $a$ takes you to $|0\rangle$ on which $N\to 0$, and if $n=0$ then $a|0\rangle=0$ and $N0=0$. Similarly if $n=1$ then $a^\dagger |1\rangle=0$, and if $n=0$ we have $a^\dagger|0\rangle =|1\rangle$ and $Na^\dagger|0\rangle= 1a^\dagger|0\rangle = (1-n) a^\dagger|0\rangle$. To show that $n=0,1$  are the only possibilitites you need to show that $a^2=(a^\dagger)^2=0$.